# Как обработать ссылки в массиве строк

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуйста, а то голова уже кипит)
Есть подобие чата в который поступают сообщения (массив messages), как можно вытащить и обработать оттуда текст содержащий http:// или https:// и заменить содержимое от первого слеша (текста ссылки) до последнего на троеточие.
Например какой-то i-тый элемент массива -> messages[i]

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    Array [
        "https://sait.com/1111/2222/33/1.jpg", 
        "Как дела", 
        "https://sait.com/c8111137237/22222/33/2.jpg", 
        "Привет"
    ]
```

Мне нужно обработать текст, чтобы получилась ссылка типа -> https://pp.userapi.com/.../fTWtBqfDhy4.jpg
Содержимое массива может быть любое, интересуют только ссылки....
Надеюсь на вашу помощь, Заранее спасибо!) 
P.S. JQuery приветствуется)

Comment: что-то вроде `.replace(/(\/\/.*?\/).*(\/[^/]*)/,"$1...$2")`

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно)